# How do I read from same starting offset in each micro batch in spark structured streaming job?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api, spark-structured-streaming

I am using spark structured streaming. Is it possible to reset Kafka offset after every batch execution so that **every batch** read from same starting offset instead of only newly discovered events?

Quoting description of `startingOffsets` from spark Kafka integration documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html)

> For streaming queries, this only applies when a new query is started,
>   and that resuming will always pick up from where the query left off.
>   Newly discovered partitions during a query will start at earliest.

Right now I am doing it by creating a static dataframe from Kafka inside for each batch loop and using a dummy streaming dataset with format as "rate". Wondering if there is a better way to do it

Comment: What is the use case for such processing?

Comment: Data that I want to read from Kafka is master data which gets updated infrequently in Kafka. I want to enrich this and write a complete snapshot of this master data to persistent storage every 1 minute.

Comment: Odd approach imho

Comment: Did you get any answer for this @conetfun?

Comment: @Akshay - I ended up using the approach I mentioned in my question description itself. Using dummy streaming dataset using rate and insde that reading from same offsets always.

Comment: @conetfun Thanks for the response. Will try to look into that.

Answer (score 0):

For Structured Streaming can set `startingOffsets` to `earliest` so that every time you consume from the earliest available offset. The following will do the trick

```
.option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
```

---

However note that this is effective just for newly created queries:

[`startingOffsets`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html)

> The start point when a query is started, either `"earliest"` which is
>   from the earliest offsets, `"latest"` which is just from the latest
>   offsets, or a json string specifying a starting offset for each
>   TopicPartition. In the json, `-2` as an offset can be used to refer to
>   earliest, `-1` to latest. Note: For batch queries, latest (either
>   implicitly or by using `-1` in json) is not allowed. **For streaming
>   queries, this only applies when a new query is started, and that
>   resuming will always pick up from where the query left off**. Newly
>   discovered partitions during a query will start at earliest.

---

Alternatively, you might also choose to change the consumer group every time:

```
.option("kafka.group.id", "newGroupID")
```

Comment: My requirement is to read from same offset in each micro batch execution. Right now in all cases (earliest, latest, specific offset), first batch will read from that offset but the subsequent batches will read from where the previous batch left off. What I am trying to do here is to read from same offset in all subsequent batches as well. There is one way to do it that I mentioned in my comment (using a dummy streaming dataset and reading actual data as static dataframe inside batch loop) but want to know if there is a better to get it done.